# Reshape from wide to long with multiple columns that have different naming patterns

Tags: r, tidyr, reshape

I have a longitudinal data set in wide format, with > 2500 columns. Almost all columns begin with 'W1_' or 'W2_' to indicate the wave (ie, time point) of data collection. In the real data, there are > 2 waves. They look like this:

```r
# Populate wide format data frame
person <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
W1_resp_sex <- c(1, 2, 1, 2)
W2_resp_sex <- c(1, 2, 1, 2)
W1_edu <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
W2_q_2_1 <- c(0, 1, 1, 0)

wide <- as.data.frame(cbind(person, W1_resp_sex, W2_resp_sex, W1_edu, W2_q_2_1))
wide
#>   person W1_resp_sex W2_resp_sex W1_edu W2_q_2_1
#> 1      1           1           1      1        0
#> 2      2           2           2      2        1
#> 3      3           1           1      3        1
#> 4      4           2           2      4        0
```

I want to reshape from wide to long format so that the data look like this:

```r
# Populate long data frame (this is how we want the wide data above to look after reshaping it)
person <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)
wave <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
sex <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2)
education <- c(1, NA, 2, NA, 3, NA, 4, NA)
q_2_1 <- c(NA, 0, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 0)

long_goal <- as.data.frame(cbind(person, wave, sex, education, q_2_1))
long_goal
#>   person wave sex education q_2_1
#> 1      1    1   1         1    NA
#> 2      1    2   1        NA     0
#> 3      2    1   2         2    NA
#> 4      2    2   2        NA     1
#> 5      3    1   1         3    NA
#> 6      3    2   1        NA     1
#> 7      4    1   2         4    NA
#> 8      4    2   2        NA     0
```

To reshape the data, I tried pivot_longer(). **How do I fix these issues?**
(I prefer not to use data.table.)

1. The variables have different naming patterns (How can I correctly specify names_pattern() ?)
2. The multiple columns (see how all values are under the 'sex' column)
3. Creating a column with 'NA' when a variable was only collected in one wave (ie, if it was only collected in wave 2, I want a column with W1_varname in which all values are NA).

```r
# Re-load wide format data
person <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
W1_resp_sex <- c(1, 2, 1, 2)
W2_resp_sex <- c(1, 2, 1, 2)
W1_edu <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
W2_q_2_1 <- c(0, 1, 1, 0)
wide <- as.data.frame(cbind(person, W1_resp_sex, W2_resp_sex, W1_edu, W2_q_2_1))

# Load package
pacman::p_load(tidyr)

# Reshape from wide to long 
long <- wide %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with('W'),
    names_to = 'Wave',
    names_prefix = 'W',
    names_pattern = '(.*)_',
    values_to = 'sex',
    values_drop_na = TRUE
  )
long
#> # A tibble: 16 × 3
#>    person Wave     sex
#>     <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
#>  1      1 1_resp     1
#>  2      1 2_resp     1
#>  3      1 1          1
#>  4      1 2_q_2      0
#>  5      2 1_resp     2
#>  6      2 2_resp     2
#>  7      2 1          2
#>  8      2 2_q_2      1
#>  9      3 1_resp     1
#> 10      3 2_resp     1
#> 11      3 1          3
#> 12      3 2_q_2      1
#> 13      4 1_resp     2
#> 14      4 2_resp     2
#> 15      4 1          4
#> 16      4 2_q_2      0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: can you show your expected output

Comment: Perhaps `pivot_longer(wide, cols = -person, names_to = c("wgrp", ".value"), names_pattern = "^(W\\d+)_(.*)$")`

Comment: You can create a custom reshape pattern with `pivot_longer_spec`.

Comment: Even with that explanation you failed to show what you want?? why ask the question if you already have what you want? ie it seems you run the `pivot_longer` function. Did you get what you want? If not what do you want then?\

Comment: Thanks, @akrun. I updated to include the expected/desired output.

Comment: @ryorlets thanks, please find the updated solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could reshape to 'long' with `pivot_longer`, specifying the `names_pattern` to capture substring from column names (`(...)`) that matches with the same order of `names_to` - i.e.. `wave` column will get the digits (`\\d+`) after the 'W', where as the `.value` (value of the columns) correspond to the substring after the first `_` in column names.  Then, we could modify the `resp_sex` and `edu` by column names

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(wide, cols = -person, names_to = c("wave", ".value"), 
    names_pattern = "^W(\\d+)_(.*)$") %>%
   rename_with(~ c("sex", "education"), c("resp_sex", "edu"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 5
  person wave    sex education q_2_1
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
1      1 1         1         1    NA
2      1 2         1        NA     0
3      2 1         2         2    NA
4      2 2         2        NA     1
5      3 1         1         3    NA
6      3 2         1        NA     1
7      4 1         2         4    NA
8      4 2         2        NA     0
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, do you have a suggestion on how to split the pattern into 2 or more patterns? It seems like this might be needed when there are hundreds (or in my case, thousands) of column names with varying patterns (I am getting the same non-reproducible error described for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684438/in-regex-mystery-error-assertion-tree-num-tags-num-tags-failed-in-execut)

Comment: @ryorlets you my have to capture it to > 2 i..e here we used only 2 groups for capturing.  So, for those patterns, it may need that many capture groups and correspnding number of names_to

Answer (score 1):

You want to reshape the variables that are measured in both waves. You may find them `table`ing the `substring` of the `names` without prefix.

```
v <- grep(names(which(table(substring(names(wide)[-1], 4)) == 2)), names(wide))
reshape2::melt(data=wide, id.vars=1, measure.vars=v)
#   person    variable value
# 1      1 W1_resp_sex     1
# 2      2 W1_resp_sex     2
# 3      3 W1_resp_sex     1
# 4      4 W1_resp_sex     2
# 5      1 W2_resp_sex     1
# 6      2 W2_resp_sex     2
# 7      3 W2_resp_sex     1
# 8      4 W2_resp_sex     2
```